# INNER JOIN code calculated value with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, inner-join

I have the following stored procedure which will generate mon to sun and then creates a temp table with a series of 'weeks' (start and end weeks) :

```
USE [test_staff]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_timesheets_all_staff_by_week_by_job_grouping_by_site]    Script Date: 03/21/2012 09:04:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_timesheets_all_staff_by_week_by_job_grouping_by_site]
    (
    @grouping_ref int,
    @week_ref int 
    )
AS

CREATE TABLE #WeeklyList
(
    Start_Week date, 
    End_Week date,
    week_ref int
    --month_name date
)


DECLARE @REPORT_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_BEGINING VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @REPORT_DATE = '2011-01-19T00:00:00'
--SELECT @REPORT_DATE = GETDATE() -- should grab the date now.
SELECT @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 1
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'TUESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 2
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'WEDNESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 3
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'THURSDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 4
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'FRIDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 5
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SATURDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 6
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SUNDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @WEEK_START_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_END_DATE DATETIME
--GET THE WEEK START DATE
SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE = @REPORT_DATE - (DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE) - 1)
--GET THE WEEK END DATE
SELECT @WEEK_END_DATE = @REPORT_DATE + (7 - DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE))
PRINT 'Week Start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_START_DATE)
PRINT 'Week End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_END_DATE)

DECLARE @Interval int = datediff(WEEK,getdate(),@WEEK_START_DATE)+1

--SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
--, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
--INTO #WeekList

INSERT INTO #WeeklyList

SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE

WHILE @Interval <= 0
    BEGIN
    set @WEEK_START_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_START_DATE)
    set @WEEK_END_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    INSERT INTO #WeeklyList values (@WEEK_START_DATE,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    SET @Interval += 1;
END

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Start_Week, 106) AS 'month_name',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), End_Week, 106) AS 'End',
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7 AS week_ref   -- create the unique week reference number
--'VIEW' AS month_name

FROM #WeeklyList
```

In this section i am creating the `week_ref`

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7 AS week_ref   -- create the unique week reference number
```

I then need to combine it with this select code:

```
    DECLARE @YearString char(3) = CONVERT(char(3), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(5), @week_ref), 1, 3))
    DECLARE @MonthString char(2) = CONVERT(char(2), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(5), @week_ref), 4, 2))

    --Convert:
    DECLARE @Year int = CONVERT(int, @YearString) + 1200
    DECLARE @Month int = CONVERT(int, @MonthString)

**--THIS FILTERS THE REPORT**     
    SELECT     ts.staff_member_ref, sm.common_name, sm.department_name, DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) AS month_name, 
                          ts.timesheet_cat_ref, cat.desc_long AS timesheet_cat_desc, grps.grouping_ref, grps.description AS grouping_desc, ts.task_ref, tsks.task_code, 
                          tsks.description AS task_desc, ts.site_ref, sits.description AS site_desc, ts.site_ref AS Expr1, 
                          CASE WHEN ts .status = 0 THEN 'Pending' WHEN ts .status = 1 THEN 'Booked' WHEN ts .status = 2 THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Invalid Status' END AS site_status, 
                          ts.booked_time AS booked_time_sum,

    start_dtm, CONVERT(varchar(20), start_dtm, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), start_dtm, 103) AS start_dtm_text, booked_time,
    end_dtm, CONVERT(varchar(20), end_dtm, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), end_dtm, 103) AS end_dtm_text


    FROM       timesheets AS ts INNER JOIN
                          timesheet_categories AS cat ON ts.timesheet_cat_ref = cat.timesheet_cat_ref INNER JOIN
                          timesheet_tasks AS tsks ON ts.task_ref = tsks.task_ref INNER JOIN
                          timesheet_task_groupings AS grps ON tsks.grouping_ref = grps.grouping_ref INNER JOIN
                          timesheet_sites AS sits ON ts.site_ref = sits.site_ref INNER JOIN
                          vw_staff_members AS sm ON ts.staff_member_ref = sm.staff_member_ref



    WHERE     (ts.status IN (1, 2)) AND (cat.is_leave_category = 0)


    GROUP BY ts.staff_member_ref, sm.common_name, sm.department_name, DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm), DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm), ts.timesheet_cat_ref, 
                          cat.desc_long, grps.grouping_ref, grps.description, ts.status, ts.booked_time, ts.task_ref, tsks.task_code, tsks.description, ts.site_ref, sits.description, ts.start_dtm, 
                          ts.end_dtm
    ORDER BY sm.common_name, timesheet_cat_desc, tsks.task_code, site_desc

    DROP TABLE #WeeklyList

    GO
```

I want to pass the `week_ref` into the SELECT statement (refer to comment - THIS FILTERS THE REPORT) but the problem is `week_ref` isnt a valid column as its derived by code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform an INNER JOIN to your weeklylist temp table on the date you need to filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I really understand the problem but I found 2 problems in the code you posted.
The inserts you make on the #WeeklyList temporary table, are missing one column in the selected values that I assume you wanted to be your variable @week_ref

I I change this, I get to the point of the final table select that I dont have.

hope this is a start to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, after this statement: WHERE     (ts.status IN (1, 2)) AND (cat.is_leave_category = 0) i want to write AND week_ref=@week_ref

Comment: the problem is the variable week_ref isnt recognised

Comment: Im sorry but I cant replicate the error, I added the "AND week_ref=@week_ref" part and I got no error creating the sp, I only have an error of "Invalid object name 'timesheets'" because I dont have that table. can you post the actual error message?